# Magento 2 "sequence_" tables

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, table

In my the Magento2-0.74.0-beta7 there are some tables related to sales entities that start with `sequence_`.

- sequence_creditmemo_0
- sequence_creditmemo_1
- sequence_invoice_0
- sequence_invoice_1
- sequence_order_0
- sequence_order_1
- sequence_shipment_0
- sequence_shipment_1

All these tables contain a single column `sequence_value`

I assume that `0` and `1` at the end of the table name are related to the store id, but what's the purpose of the tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I happened to notice this table.

In case you're still interested, it records the increment_id for order/invoice/shipment of your store.

e.g. Place a new order, it increases by 1.

Set it to 1000000, your next order id will be 1000001.

Comment: Oh. I've forgot about this. Yes I'm still interested since I haven't found an answer yet. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Yep. It seams that's what it does. It holds the last increment id without the prefix.

Comment: Magento 1 developers can relate this to `eav_entity_store.increment_last_id`

Comment: I think it records the entity_id. The value of increment_id can be different than the value of the sequence id

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it's to improve concurrency. I think it goes faster than using MySQL auto allocation. Eg you can grab 100 ids in a single update for batch loads. Or preallocate an id before inserting the real record etc.

Comment: OK. But what do they store? Or what code uses those tables?