# What is the table sequence_cms_block for?

Tags: magento2, database

So when trying to **schedule a CMS** update we were getting a **foreign key** constraint **error**.  This was related to `sequence_cms_block` and `cms_block`.

It seems like `sequence_cms_block` is a single column and simply repeats `block_id` from the `cms_block`.  I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of this table since these two queries appear to be equivalent:

Select `block_id` from cms_block

```
Select * from sequence_cms_block
```

So I'd love to understand, why does the `sequence_table` exist?

Answer (score 0):

It records the increment id for cms block. Create a new cms block and it will be increased by 1.

[reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/109713/20064)

Comment: That does seem to be how it works, but I'm still confused on the why?  SQL allows for block_id to auto-increment so why have an entirely new table just to hold the same values?